# Java: How do I kill a background process automatically when the main application is stopped?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, processbuilder

I'm trying to use Java to launch a Gradle process that performs a continuous build in the background. Here is my code:

```
final var updateTimestampProcess =
      new ProcessBuilder("gradlew.bat", "compileGroovy", "--continuous")
                .directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")))
                .inheritIO()
     try {
         updateTimestampProcess.start()
     } catch (IOException ignored) {}
```

It works, but the process doesn't terminate when I use IntelliJ's Stop command. I have to use Task Manager to hunt down the Java process that's running the `gradlew` command and end it manually.

How can I amend my code so that the background process is terminated when the main process stops?

Comment: There is no foolproof way to do this.  If your Java process gets forcibly killed, a shutdown hook will not be invoked.  If you're running in an IDE the shutdown hook may not be invoked until the JVM terminates (depending on how the IDE manages debug/run sessions).  The usual way this is handled in Linux is for processes to write their PID to a file, usually in `/var/run/[programname].pid` and then check on startup to see if that process is still running.

Comment: @JimGarrison What I am expecting is that when I presss the Stop button in IntelliJ, the main application terminates, and I have the opportunity to  restart it immediately after. What happens is that the IDE hangs while it waits for the Gradle sub process to complete (which it never would). I'm trying to get the Gradle sub process to die when I kill the main application.

Comment: By the way, `.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")))` does nothing.  The default directory for executing a child process is already the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shutdown hook.

Add some code in the shutdown hook to kill the process you spawned.

```
Runtime
    .getRuntime()
    .addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.out.println("killing the thing")));
```

Further Reading:

https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-shutdown-hooks

Comment: It looks like I also have to use IntelliJ's Exit button in order to have the shutdown hook fire. No good since I'd like to use the Stop and Rerun shortcut button during development quite a lot. I think I might have to delegate this to an external script or something...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an external script to kill a process, I needed to do something similar not long ago. When I start my app, I write the PID to a file, and when I need to shut it down, I have this script reading that PID and then killing it:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
PIDS_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR}/pids/"

#
# Kills all the processes associated with a CWS ID
#
kill_cws() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Invalid number of arguments. Expected 0."
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "[INFO] Stopping CWS..."

  for f in "${PIDS_DIR}/cws_"*".pid"; do
    kill_cws_process "${f}"
  done

  echo "[INFO] CWS Stopped"
}

#
# Kills a specific process
#
kill_cws_process() {
  local pid_file="$1"
  local pid
  pid=$(cat "${pid_file}")

  echo "[INFO][PID=${pid}] Killing CWS instance"
  kill -9 "${pid}"
  ev=$?
  if [ "${ev}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "[WARN][PID=${pid}] Error killing PID"
  fi

  echo "[INFO][PID=${pid}] Waiting for instance termination"

  echo "[INFO][PID=${pid}] Clean instance PID file"
  rm "${pid_file}"
  ev=$?
  if [ "${ev}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "[WARN][PID=${pid}] Error deleting pid file ${pid_file}"
  fi
}

#
# MAIN
#
kill_cws "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of reading, I realize that while this is possible, I have not found a fully workable solution. As a work-around, I used the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/third_party_integration.html) to devise the following solution:

```
final ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector
            .newConnector()
            .forProjectDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")))
            .connect()
try {
  connection
    .newBuild()
    .forTasks("compileGroovy")
    .withArguments("--continuous")
    .setStandardOutput(System.out)
    .run()
} catch (BuildException ignored) {
 // Ignored for testing
}
```

It's neat and it solves all of the process management issues.

Answer (score 0):

this groovy script terminates external process on main thread end.

not saying it's nice but it works

```
def procBuilder =
    new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe")
        .inheritIO()

def mainThread = Thread.currentThread()

//not a daemon to avoid termination..
Thread.start {
    try {
        println "daemon start"
        def proc = procBuilder.start()
        println "daemon process started"
        mainThread.join()
        println "daemon process killing..."
        proc.destroy()
        println "daemon process end"
    } catch(e) {
        println "daemon error: $e"
    }
}

println "main thread sleep"
Thread.sleep(5000)
println "main thread end"
```